# Included Makefile with Linux Documentation not working

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, python-sphinx

I am trying to create associated docs to do with the [Linux kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux). As seen [here](https://docs.kernel.org/process/kernel-docs.html#kernel-docs). I have the repository cloned. At the top-level, when I run `make xmldocs` I receive the error:

> sphinx-build returned an error at ./scripts/sphinx-pre-install line 317

> make[1]: *** [Documentation/Makefile:137: xmldocs] Error 1

> make: *** [Makefile: 1816: xmldocs] Error 2

Within `linux/Documentation`, I get this error:

> make: /scripts/sphinx-pre-install: No such file or directory

> make: *** [Makefile: 137: xmldocs] Error 127

How do I resolve this to build the docs?

Answer (score -1):

The  README file explains how to build the docs. Run  `make htmldocs` in the top directory.  See https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/README

Comment: I also get an error. Updated post.

Comment: possibly that is why xmldocs is not listed in the README as a valid target. Or, possibly you did not clean up after running make in the Documentation directory.

Comment: `make htmldocs` doesn't work either, and `xmldocs` it is listed as a target under `linux/Documentation/Makefile`

Comment: @user129393192 It looks like you run your stuff in upper folder?! You need to run the make command inside the Linux kernel source tree which comes from Git repository. Also don't forget to install `sphinx`.

Comment: The requirements are listed in changes.rst https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/process/changes.rst

Comment: I believe the error is in my installation of `sphinx`. It was installed at `/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages` by pacman, but my `python` defaults to `3.9.7`.